# Split text By specific keyword

Tags: python, algorithm, split

I have a list and I want to add the words that come after a certain word in this list into a new list.

**exp input**

```
list =["split","foo","foo","foo","split","mama","mama","split","orange","melon"]
```

**exp output**

```
list =["split","foo","foo","foo"]
      ["split","mama", "mama"   ]
      ["split","orange","melon" ]
```

I encountered a logical error, I checked each child of the list and tried to throw the objects up to the next argument into a new list.

```
for i in liste:
    if i.lower() == "split":
        x = True
    if x:
        new_list.append(i)
```

I don't know what to do after the first loop. How can I reset the bool value and create a new list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply iterate and keep a track of the current visisted set.

```py
l =["split","foo","foo","foo","split","mama","mama","split","orange","melon"]
ans = []
curr = []
split_word = "split"
for i in l:
    if i != split_word:
        curr.append(i)
    else:
        if curr:
            ans.append(curr)
        curr = [i]
if curr:
    ans.append(curr)

print(ans)
# [['split', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo'], ['split', 'mama', 'mama'], ['split', 'orange', 'melon']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a flag, you can append to the output list an empty sub-list when the input is `'split'`, and keep appending the current string to the last sub-list in the output:

```
lst =["split","foo","foo","foo","split","mama","mama","split","orange","melon"]

output = []
for s in lst:
    if s == 'split':
        output.append([])
    output[-1].append(s)
print(output)
```

This outputs:

```
[['split', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo'], ['split', 'mama', 'mama'], ['split', 'orange', 'melon']]
```

Comment: This will crash for `["foo","foo","foo","split"]`

Comment: What would be the expected output in that case? The OP did not specify, so it's likely it won't ever be the case.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `list Comprehension` :

```py
l =["split","foo","foo","foo","split","mama","mama","split","orange","melon"]


idx = [0, len(l)]
[idx.insert(-1, i) for i, value in enumerate(l) if value == "split"]   
splitted_l = [l[idx[i]:idx[i+1]] for i in range(len(idx)-1)]    # Because idx[i+1] we just need to check (len(idx)-1)
```

*result :*

```py
# splitted_l : 

[[],
 ['split', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo'],
 ['split', 'mama', 'mama'],
 ['split', 'orange', 'melon']]
```

- **Because of first `split` in *list* it creates an empty list at first. you can delete empty list if you want :**

```py
idx = [0, len(l)]
[idx.insert(-1, i) for i, value in enumerate(l) if value == "split"]   
splitted_l = [l[idx[i]:idx[i+1]] for i in range(len(idx)-1)]

if splitted_l[0] == [] : splitted_l.remove([])    # Delete empty list at first if exist
```

*result :*

```py
# splitted_l : 

[['split', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo'],
 ['split', 'mama', 'mama'],
 ['split', 'orange', 'melon']]
```